# Remove general drift from data? (Spectral Analysis)

Tags: spectral-theory, signal-processing

I am working on separating a song from a moving source. The recordings all have a drift since the sound source itself is moving. This means that the information that I am interested in (the higher frequencies) has a drift with a low frequency. I don't have enough reputation to embed a picture, but it looks something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/31NRF.jpg

Where the red line is the drift (movement of the sound source) I am referring to, and the faster oscillations is the song that I am interested in.

Because all of my signals have a somewhat random drift, I would like to remove this and centralize it around $y=0$, in order to do the spectral analysis more consistent.

The easiest that comes to mind is of course something similar to a highpass filter, but that distorts the spectrum heavily. Other ideas are MA-filter on segments of the signal, and subtract that signal from the original one. Maybe model the low-frequency signal and subtract?

All of my alternatives seems to distort the spectrum quite a bit, and it is important that it is kept quite intact.

Do you have any ideas that could help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: That's the general drift. The datasets generally look like this - but this one I just drew in Paint to visualize what I meant for simplicity and clarity.

Comment: It is experimental data. The black data is a song (like Bohemian Rhapsody) - the red line represents the movement of the sound source (i.e. a speaker), that has physically been moved around, and so the strength in the signal is varying, creating this low-frequency drift in the signal. The data in the picture has not been tampered with at all, it's original experimental data. Red curve was just to illustrate.

Comment: What is so hard to understand about the figure? It's a song, so it has intensity (vert. axis) and time/samples (hor. axis). The signal is the black line, and the red line represents how the intensity varies since the physical source of the sound is being physically moved in the physical world from a physical person physically touching the speaker and physically walking around with it in a physical room. Yes agreed, I still do not think you will understand.